# How to fold all the second level section in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm using the readthedocs theme for a personal sphinx documentation project. Everything works fine except the display of the left frame of the content list: It display all level of section headings, without showing any hierarchy. How to let it show levels as in most readthedocs documentation project?

[image]

After click the + sign, it looks right:

[image]

This is how I mark the section title:

```
Apache
======
How to restart
--------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like this bug: [Toc not expanding](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/445).

If not, please include your version of Sphinx, where you build the docs, and whether what you do to build the docs satisfies the conditions of that issue.

Otherwise, there is no configurable option to expand all options in the for the RTD Sphinx theme. See https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring.html#toc-options You will have to write custom JavaScript to make it so, and include the static asset with the theme. That homework is left to the questioner or a gracious answerer.

You could also file a feature request at https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of sphinx. The section that you select expands on the left side bar. Else, it remains collapsed. https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versions.html this link also shows similar kind of behavior. To make it collapsible on clicking, you will require to update the theme.